# IndexError: list index out of range - python 3.8

Tags: python, list, indexing

Alright. I have seen quite a few questions like this on StackOverflow, but none really helped me. I am working on a python script that moves some base32 code around. Here is the problematic function:

```py
def getCode():
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = 0
    base32 = input("Please paste your code below:\n")
    base32 = base32.split("#")
    while i < len(base32):
        base32[i] = base32[i].split(",")
        i += 1
        while j < len(base32[i]):
            base32[i[j]] = base32[i[j]].split(" ")
            j += 1
            while k < len(base32[i[j]]):
                if base32[i[[j[k]]]] == "":
                    base32.list_splice(k, 1)
                k += 1
            if base32[i[j]].len() == 0:
                base32[i].list_splice(j, 1)
    return base32
```

I defined `list_splice()` earlier. I also declared `getCode()` after this. When I run it, it asks me for my code, but when I hit enter after, it gives me this:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gabri\SynologyDrive\track_mover.py", line 43, in <module>
    getCode()
  File "C:\Users\gabri\SynologyDrive\track_mover.py", line 32, in getCode
    while j < len(base32[i]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am not sure why. From what I understand, a IndexError generally refers to passing in a list index that is too high, like if you have a string with 3 characters and pass `list[3]`. I have no idea why it is saying this. I would think that the
while loop would keep it from getting out of hand, but maybe not? I have tried all kinds of lengths of strings that I paste into it, but that doesn't seem to be the answer.

===

## EDIT

I tried Mustafa Aydın's answer, and while that does fix some things, it now outputs this:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gabri\SynologyDrive\track_mover.py", line 44, in <module>
    getCode()
  File "C:\Users\gabri\SynologyDrive\track_mover.py", line 33, in getCode
    base32[i[j]] = base32[i[j]].split(" ")
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I have no idea why it is doing this.
I also got some questions regarding the `list_splice()` function. What it is is the python equivalent of the javascript `.splice()` built-in function. Here is the code for it:

```py
def list_splice(target, start, delete_count=None, *items):
    """Remove existing elements and/or add new elements to a list.

    target        the target list (will be changed)
    start         index of starting position
    delete_count  number of items to remove (default: len(target) - start)
    *items        items to insert at start index

    Returns a new list of removed items (or an empty list)
    """
    if delete_count == None:
        delete_count = len(target) - start

    # store removed range in a separate list and replace with *items
    total = start + delete_count
    removed = target[start:total]
    target[start:total] = items

    return removed
```

If it helps any, here is the JavaScript I am converting from:

```js
function loadCode(input) {
  var base32 = document.getElementById(input).value;
  var base32 = base32.split("#");
  for (var i = 0; i < base32.length; i++) {
    base32[i] = base32[i].split(",");
    for (var j = 0; j < base32[i].length; j++) {
      base32[i][j] = base32[i][j].split(" ");
      for (var k = 0; k < base32[i][j].length; k++) {
        if (base32[i][j][k] == "") {
          base32[i][j].splice(k, 1);
        }
      }
      if (base32[i][j].length == 0) {
        base32[i].splice(j, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  return base32;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What are the inputs that you've tried which caused this error??

Comment: I have tried several, the largest being:
-18 1i 18 1i,4d -8n -t -5l,-31 -3r -51 p,-55 33 -11 6n,bb 6b bv -11,8t -67 45 -61,2n -n 15 8p,-1j a3 -27 9t,-5l 51 -5l t,-3r -j 1p -2r,21 -2t 23 -2t,2f -2n 23 -2j,-1j -15 -2d -7,-23 j -1l h,-1h -b -1r 2b,-15 -d -27 3p,-25 2v 2l 2j,-r 2j 2b 1t f -25,l -17 -23 -j##
I can also add the other function if you would like to try it out yourself.

Comment: What is `base32.list_splice`?

Comment: @tdelaney it is a function I have that is the equivalent of the Javascript .splice() function.

Comment: `base32` is a list that's not a standard `list` method.

Comment: well, yes, because it is a custom function. It does affect lists. - check out the edit

Comment: @ThePurpleBuccaneer Yes it is a custom function, but it doesn't magically become a part of `list` object's method family :) In python, (unlike javascript :)), you cannot freely add an attribute/method to built-in things. I edited my answer to respond these.

Comment: @MustafaAydın - I am completely aware of that. We are both in agreement that `list.list_splice` is not a thing. The question was why you have `base32.list_splice(k ,1)` in your code. I was simply scanning your code looking for odd uses `base32` and that popped out.

Comment: @tdelaney, wrong mention i guess :)

Comment: @tdelaney, oh i see now. I copied OP's code and only fixed the very original issue: loop incremental thing. And in my edit to the answer, I fixed those issues, too. Also I was commenting to OP not you while saying `list.list_splice` is erroneous.

Comment: @MustafaAydın While I really appreciate all of this, I ran your code and it gave me an IndexError: list index out of range for while k < len(base32[i][j]): # <- subscript issue was here

Comment: @MustafaAydın sorry, that made no difference.

Comment: I see now, you need to reset those counters `j` and `k` back to zero when their while loops end. You can undo the last comment's change (you know the logical workings of the code better, i'm looking on a higher level).

Comment: @MustafaAydın so I would redeclare j=0 and k=0 at the end of the loop? If so, it is still giving me the same error. could you please edit your answer?

Comment: see my (hopefully last time) edited answer :)

Comment: Seeing your js version, you should convert `list_splice(base32, k, 1)` to `list_splice(base32[i][j], k, 1)`

Comment: @MustafaAydın nope, sorry. same error.

Comment: @ThePurpleBuccaneer, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should increment `i` after you are done with the `i`'th item of the `base32` list. Also (response to your edit), accessing a list element in a 2-dimensional fashion is done as `base32[i][j]` i.e. you first reach to i'th item, then reach to j'th item of that item. Similar applies to `base32[i][j][k]`.

Edit: Seeing your javascript code, I'd say that you should be using `for` loops in python also. Those will be less error prone. Also, the splicing you are doing (only removing one item) can be done with `pop`. Lastly, removing elements whilst iterating over a list is not a good idea; one solution is to iterate in reverse order. So, putting all these together, you end up with this:

```
def getCode():
    base32 = input("Please paste your code below:\n")
    base32 = base32.split("#")
    for i in reversed(range(len(base32))):
        base32[i] = base32[i].split(",")
        for j in reversed(range(len(base32[i]))):
            base32[i][j] = base32[i][j].split(" ")
            for k in reversed(range(len(base32[i][j]))):
                if base32[i][j][k] == "":
                    base32[i][j].pop(k)
            if len(base32[i][j]) == 0:
                base32[i].pop(j)
    return base32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while i < len(base32):
    base32[i] = base32[i].split(",")
    i += 1
    while j < len(base32[i]):
```

On the final iteration of this loop, the loop condition `i < len(base32)` is still true, so the loop executes one last time.  But then `i` is incremented inside the loop, so now `base32[i]` is out-of-bounds.

Generally, incrementing a loop variable should be done at the bottom of the loop, so that no code executes with a possibly-too-large value of the loop variable.